# ASP.NET core all model values are null when passing a model to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, partials

Goal: I have a page that I want to have a return url passed through the model of the view so upon completion of the form, it will return to the previous url. The page is a address validation and add it to the account as a saved address.

Flow of the page: You are presented with an address form to fill out. on completion, you will have a button that will call to a controller method that will verify with FedEx via API, and then if valid, it will let you save the address.

Issue: once you press the Verify Address button, it seems to have an issue with sending the form data to the controller.

HTTPGET:

```
public ActionResult AddShippingAddress(string strReturnURL)
{
    // get states
    ViewBag.states = GetStates();
    DeliveryAddressModel model = new DeliveryAddressModel();
    model.strReturnAddress = strReturnURL;
    return View(model);
}
```

AddShippingAddress.chshtml

```
@model EcommerceWebsite.Models.Home.DeliveryAddressModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Shipping Address";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<br />
<div class="container">
    <partial id="ValidateAddress"></partial>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <h4>Shipping Address</h4>
        <hr />

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Name</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Attention To</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strAttnTo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strAttnTo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Street</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strStreet1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strStreet1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Street 2</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strStreet2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strStreet2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>City</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strCity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strCity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @{
                IEnumerable<SelectListItem> dataItems = ViewBag.states;
            }
            <div class="form-group">
                <h5>State</h5>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State.IntStateId, dataItems, "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State.IntStateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Zip</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strZip, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strZip, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Phone Number</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strPhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strPhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Set as Default</h5>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.blnIsDefault)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.blnIsDefault, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ajax-method="get" data-toggle="ajax-modal"
                        data-url="@Url.Action("GetValidationOnAddress", new { model = Model })">
                    Verify Address
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>


<script>

    $(function () {
        var PlaceHolderElement = $('#ValidateAddress');
        $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).data('url');
            // get the form containing the submit button
            var form = $(this).closest('form')
            // serialize all the fields in the form
            var model = form.serialize();
            // the the request to the url along with the form (model) data
            $.get(url, model).done(function (data) {
                PlaceHolderElement.html(data);
                PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
                //$('#ValidateAddress').modal('show');
            })
        })
    })

</script>
```

Here is the partial:

```
@model EcommerceWebsite.Models.Home.DeliveryAddressModel


<div class="modal fade" id="ValidateAddress">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="ValidateAddressLabel">Validate Address</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("AddShippingAddressToUser", "Home"))
            {

                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.strName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.strAttnTo)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.strStreet1)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.strStreet2)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.strCity)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.State.StrStateCode)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.State.StrStateName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.State.IntStateId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.strZip)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.strPhoneNumber)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.blnIsDefault)
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="Create">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @if (Model.ErrorMessage == null)
                            {
                                <h5>@Model.strName</h5>
                                @if (Model.strAttnTo != null)
                                {<h5>@Model.strAttnTo</h5>}
                                <h5>@Model.strStreet1</h5>
                                @if (Model.strStreet2 != null)
                                {<h5>@Model.strStreet2</h5>}
                                <h5>@Model.strCity</h5>
                                <h5>@Model.State.StrStateCode</h5>
                                <h5>@Model.strZip</h5>
                                <h5>@Model.strPhoneNumber</h5>

                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                    <button type="button" value="Edit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <h4>@Model.ErrorMessage</h4>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When all is said and done and the get validation button is pressed, it's supposed to send all the data to the controller and Verify the address with FedEx. But everything is null..

[image]

**Now something to note, when I change the return of the httpget to `return View();` everything works except it doesn't send the URL.**

Update:

The `AddShippingAddressToUser()` hasn't even been called yet. The error lies somewhere in lines 101 - 102. Inside the button or the line 618 on the home controller.

[image]

Update: Here's the Model

```
public class DeliveryAddressModel
    {
        //[Required]
        //[Display(Name = "First & Last Name")]
        public string strName { get; set; }
        //[Display(Name = "Attention To")]
        public string strAttnTo { get; set; }
        //[Required]
        //[Display(Name = "Street 1")]
        public string strStreet1 { get; set; }
        //[Display(Name = "Street 2")]
        public string strStreet2 { get; set; }
        //[Required]
        //[Display(Name = "City")]
        public string strCity { get; set; }
        //[Required]
        //[Display(Name = "State")]
        public Tstate State { get; set; }
        //[Required]
        //[Display(Name = "Zipcode")]
        public string strZip { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "You must provide a phone number")]
        //[Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        //[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        //[RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid phone number")]
        public string strPhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public bool blnIsDefault { get; set; }


        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public string strReturnAddress { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: .closest("form") could be the issue.  You've got a few, and two are nested which should not be allowed (in the partial).  Give the form an id and use that to get the form data.  Then you could do something like formresult = $('#' + formID).serialize();

Comment: avoid the nesting... you can set different actions for different submit buttons.  (I would avoid viewbag, too... just bind a viewmodel class...)

Comment: @pcalkins The reason for the nesting is I'm calling to Fedex for verification without reloading the page. once it's been verified, the user needs to accept the new address that fedex has decided it was, and THEN it is saved.

Comment: That nesting should be avoided... there are other ways to deal with it.  (consider returning JSON to your script and having the JS update things...)  For the problem at hand I think you might try removing , new { model = Model } from the data-url attribute.  Seems like that would create a null... and might confuse the model/argument binding. 
Posting the form data also seems a bit more practical... just keep all fields being passed to the controller in the form.  Right now you are basically building a big URL with key/value pairs because of the GET.

Comment: jQuery may even send something odd there like, "?model=Model?formfieldname=value&formfieldname2=value2"... might be two ?  The .get() method is going to construct the URL.  (also using the standard _layout.cshtml stuff can cause some odd behavior because of @renderbody... you may want to implement your own static header/footer... don't think that's the problem here, but something to be aware of if you see double-GETS or POSTS happening in the future.)

Comment: Hi @Scott Uphus, it seems your form submit does not send the model.  I try to post the model with multiple string type property and one bool type property. It works fine. Maybe your model design is not same with what I assume.  Could you pls share your `DeliveryAddressModel`?

Comment: @ScottUphus Try encoding the model before sending it to your `JS` function: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ajax-method="get" data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-url="@Url.Action("GetValidationOnAddress", new { model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))})">`

Comment: @RahulSharma encoding it is producing another error I'm not sure how to handle. Also, I'm not sending the GetValidationOnAddress to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, since your form's function isnt a retrieval operation and a creational operation, use the http verb POST and not GET. Replace the HttpVerb filter above your action from HttpGet to HttpPost.

Second add this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddShippingAddressToUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

Alternatively,

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddShippingAddressToUser", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
```

Before your model in the action add: [FromQuery]

Comment: The issue isn't in the AddShippingAddressToUser, it's in the Verify Address button on the main view